# How to collect for-loop output in logical way

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I probably just have tired eyes here, but I am not sure what I am messing up on my nested for loop. I am trying to iterate through years and then months of our internal sales data to get a df (for eventual charting) of for our speed of sales, seasonality, etc. For some reason, I keep getting the first year of data overwritten in all the columns.

Just about every syntactical adjustment I can think of. I think I have tired eyes...

```
annual_sales = [] # make empty list for revenue data
annual_sales_df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(1, 13)) # make empty df to collect lists

for i in range(2013, currentYear):
    for j in range(0, 12 + 1):
        annual_sales.append(df.loc[(df['stageName'] == 'Awarded Won') & (df['fiscalYear'] == i) & (df['Month'] == j), 'revenue'].sum()) # collect annual revenue in a list - this part is working correctly, I just left it in for context
    out_df = pd.DataFrame(annual_sales) # put sales list into df
    annual_sales_df = annual_sales_df.merge(annual_out_df, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'inner') # merge the intermediate df onto the larger df as columns
print(annual_sales_df) # print the df
```

I expect to get each year of sales by month in a column, and 6 columns of data from 2013-2018 making up a 6 x 12 df. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `for j in range(0, 12 + 1):` This will produce 13 numbers, from 0 to 12 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The `range()` function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from `0` by default, and increments by `1` (by default), and ends at a specified number.

**Syntax:**

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

Here, one important thing to note is that the stop is exclusive. So, if you want to run a loop from 1 to 12(which is 12 months overall), replace `for j in range(0, 12 + 1)`
with `for j in range(1, 13)`.

Also, there is a wrong dataframe passed inside `merge()`. There is no `annual_out_df` dataframe that was created before, but there is `out_df`. So, I think, it should be `out_df` in place of `annual_out_df` in that function.

Answer (score 0):

1). Use -->>   for j in range(1,13)
  .  # Here 1 is included and 13 is excluded.
     #range(start,end,step)

2). "annual_sales_df.merge(annual_out_df, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'inner') ".
  Here there is no dataframe with name annual_out_df, use out_df.

```
annual_sales = [] 
annual_sales_df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(1, 13))
for i in range(2013, currentYear):
    for j in range(1, 13):  # New Change
        annual_sales.append(df.loc[(df['stageName'] == 'Awarded Won') & 
        (df['fiscalYear'] == i) & (df['Month'] == j), 'revenue'].sum()) 
    out_df = pd.DataFrame(annual_sales) 
    annual_sales_df = annual_sales_df.merge(out_df, left_index = True, 
    right_index = True, how = 'inner')      # New Change
print(annual_sales_df)
```

Comment: hey guys - thanks for the answers. I made the edits, but I am still getting the first year data repeated for each column (6 times), and I am only seeing 11 months of data instead of 12. An outer join lets me see all 12  months of data but gives me each subsequent year appended to the last in columns. I am trying to get each year of data by month in its own column. Is there something else I am doing wrong?